# QT Text Edit/Text Browser dynamic height

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qtextedit

I am very new to QT, I have created a a GUI application which has the following code:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Using the designer I have made a textEdit in a form layout. When I have too much content in the textEdit it makes a scroll bar instead of adjusting the size to the content.

I have googled like a mad, but all the answers I have found was way above my level so I simply didnt understand them. I want to achieve this very badly since is the core of my gui.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you want the size to adapt to the content? Do you want the entire window to resize? Is the `QTextEdit` a `centralWidget` of the `MainWindow`? You should not use designer, and simply create the ui programmatically in a minimal test case. Put it all into one file, no need to split it up - remember, this is a test case, not a software project.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do this. Here is my workaround:

Header:

```
class Text_edit_auto_height : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit Text_edit_auto_height(QTextEdit* edit);

private:
  QTextEdit* _edit;
  bool eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event);

  QTimer timer;

private slots:
  void update_height();

};
```

Source:

```
#include "Text_edit_auto_height.h"
#include <QEvent>

Text_edit_auto_height::Text_edit_auto_height(QTextEdit* edit) :
  QObject(edit)
, _edit(edit)
{
  connect(edit->document(), SIGNAL(contentsChanged()), this, SLOT(update_height()));
  update_height();
  edit->installEventFilter(this);
  connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update_height()));
  timer.start(500);
}

bool Text_edit_auto_height::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event) {
  if (event->type() == QEvent::Resize) {
    update_height();
  }
  return false;
}

void Text_edit_auto_height::update_height() {
  _edit->setFixedHeight(_edit->document()->size().height() + 5);
}
```

Usage: put this in the constructor:

```
new Text_edit_auto_height(ui->list);
```